# Having been deceived so much, I am now on my guard. What's on my guard: adverbial phrase or adjective phrase?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> Having been deceived so much, I am now on my guard.

Q: on my guard

Prepositional phrase is used as adverbial or adjective phrase.
What's the case for the example?

Comment: You can find that in dictionaries. Have you tried? :)

Comment: It's a **preposition phrase** functioning as subjective predicative **complement** of "am". We know it's a complement because it is required to complete the verb phrase.

Comment: complement is noun, or adjective. So it's adjective.

Comment: @Brandon That's nonsense! Complements can most certainly be preposition phrases. Compare "He was **in the garden**" / "I am **in your debt**", where the phrases in bold are PPs functioning as obligatory complements.